# How can I "append" html to a view in nodeJS?

Tags: html, arrays, node.js, html-table, append

I have an array of data in NodeJS that I am attempting to "append" to a view (.ejs file) which is already full of html. I'm using the <%= %> system to render the file and pass the data through. This would be simple for me to do however the number of variables in the array are constantly variable (I.e. Sometimes it has 5 objects, sometimes 3). It would be easy to hard code the <%= %> elements if it was consistent but as it is not, I am looking for a way to "append" html tables to the view. I have seen some examples of this but those examples use different methods of rendering to the client which I cannot incorporate into my system. Any help would be appreciated. I'm sorry if this is not clear or if this question already exists but I could not find any questions anywhere that suit my solution and I am getting desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this .

Suppose your array name is result and you want to pass this array to "ejs" template then you can use for loop to iterate through no of elements in array. So it doesn't matter how many no of elements you have in your array it will display all.

result = ['data1','data2','data3','data4']

put below code in ejs template.  (of course modify according to your requirement)

```
 <table>
    <thead">
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <% for(var i=0;i < result.length;i++) { %>
        </tr>

        <td>     
                <%= result[i] %>
        </td>

        <% } %>
      </tr>
 </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Answers exactly what I needed to know. Thank you so much! :)